# Continuous extension of step function from $\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Consider $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge 0$.  On $\mathbb{R}$, this is discontinuous at $0$.  Restricted to $X\equiv \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, $f$ is continuous but has no continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$.  However, consider $f$ restricted to $Y\equiv \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$.  $Y\subset X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, countable, and $f$ is continuous on it.  $f|_Y$ therefore should have a unique continuous extension $g$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Obviously, $g$ cannot equal $f$ everywhere on $X$ or it also would constitute an extension of $f$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  I assume $g$ looks like $0$ for $x\le 0$ and has some bizarre oscillatory behavior for $x>0$ which lands it on $1$ for rational values, has limit $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$, and is continuous for $x>0$.  I'm sure I'll kick myself when the answer turns out to be trivial, but does anyone have insight into what $g$ would be?

Comment: Based on what do you conclude that $f|_Y$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I believe that there is a theorem that any continuous function on a countable dense subset of $R$ has a unique continuous extension to $R$.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Any two continuous functions that coincide on dense sets must be equal. so if $f|_Y$ has a continuous extension then when we restrict that extension to $X$ it will equal $f|_X$. So if  $f|_Y$ has an extension, so will $f|_X$.

Comment: I don't quite see how this follows.  If $f$ has continuous extensions $g$ and $h$ from both $X$ and $Y$ to $R$, then indeed $g|_X= h|_X= f|_X$ and $g=h$ since (as you say) if fns are equal on a dense subset they must be equal everywhere.  But if only $Y$ has an extension $h$, then there is no reason $h|_X= f|_X$.  In fact, by this very token it cannot be.  $h$ must equal $f$ on $Y$, but must differ from $f$ on at some points in $X-Y$.

Comment: You didn't get my argument. Suppose $f|_Y$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$, called $h$. Then $h|_X$ is also continuous on $X$ and hence equal to $f$ (since they coincide on a dense set, $Y$ being a dense subset of $X$). Then $h$ is also a continuous extension of $f$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$ since $h=f$ on $X$, and $h$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Yeah, that makes sense, and actually clarifies things a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake lies in the statement 'therefore should have a unique continuous extension'. I assume that you use theorem:

- $A\subset X$ is dense
- $Y$ is complete
- $f\colon A\to Y$ is uniformly continuous.

Then there exists a unique continuous extension.

Which of these assumptions isn't satisfied?

Comment: The thm I mentioned certainly could be based on this.  I'm not sure which of these fails, though.  $Q-\{0\}$ is dense in $R$.  $f$ seems to me to be uniformly continuous on $Q-\{0\}$ (since it is constant on each of two disconnected domains $(Q-\{0\})\cap R^-$ and $(Q-\{0\})\cap R^+$).  $\{0,1\}$ strikes me as complete because it has no Cauchy sequences so every Cauchy sequence converges.   Maybe I'm being too glib about uniform continuity?  I'm not sure how that would work for a disconnected space, but I assume it devolves to each connected component?  Which of these am I wrong about?

Comment: Of course, $Y$ here really is $R$ I suppose, since that's the space we're allowing the extension to use.  But $R$ is complete too.  So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I should clarify that I am referring to your $Y$, not my $Y$ from the statement of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for $Y$. Take $x=-1/n$ and $x'=1/n$. We see that $f(x)=0$ and $f(x')=1$. Can it be uniformly continuous?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit rusty when it comes to uniform continuity.  We're talking about uniform continuity on $Q-{0}$ so would $(-1/n,1/n)$ count as an interval?  My recollection was that for any $\epsilon$ there must be some global $\delta$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(x')|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x'|<\delta$.  However, here we have two disconnected regions.  Uniform continuity holds in each separately.  Do we require that it hold across the missing point $0$ too?  As I said, my analysis is a bit rusty (hence the exploration involving this question in the first place).

Comment: Or is it just a matter of balls in a metric space, so the ball still exists even if $0$ isn't in it?

Comment: Don't think of intervals. The arguments $x$ and $x'$ can be arbitrarily close to each other ($|x-x'|$ can be smaller than any $\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(x')|$ is large (equals one).

Comment: My guess is that the theorem I cited actually derives from the Tietze extension theorem, which says that a continuous function on a closed subspace of a normal space has a continuous extension.    A countable subset is closed, and the spaces $R$ and $R-\{0\}$ are normal (any disjoint closed sets have disjoint open neighborhoods).   So this would seem to apply.  Not sure where uniqueness would come from, though.

Comment: No, $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ isn't closed! By no means.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the uniform continuity aspect!  And, my bad, you're absolutely right about $Q$ and $Q-\{0\}$.  I guess that I need to dig through my ancient notes and find where the thm I cited actually came from (or if I completely misunderstood it).  I suspect that it really referenced uniform continuity and your answer is the solution to my conundrum.  Glad I didn't waste a lot of time trying to find the extension :)  Thanks again for patiently helping me work through this!